# Saving file to windows-viewable folder rather than emulated/0/[foldername]

Tags: android, save, storage, local-storage

I am doing some android development work and have been saving files to the sdcard by using the code:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

This works great but the problem is, my app creates a lot of images I want to be able to grab when the phone is attached as a USB stick to a Windows PC so instead of going into storage/emulated/0/ I want the data to go into the windows-viewable folder (the parent of DCIM etc.)

What is the safest way of doing this? (So it will work on many devices without millions of hacks)

Thanks for your time,

Poncho